# Передача массива

Tags: javascript

Ребят, добрый день.
Вопрос такой, получаю массив, перебираю его, получаю ключи, и хочу передать его дальше, но передается только последний элемент, а нужно передать все.

Код следующий:

```
for (var i = 0; i < getListOrder.length; i++) {
                    listOrder = {
                        externalItemId: getListOrder[i].ProductId,
                        name: getListOrder[i].Name,
                        category: getListOrder[i].Categories[0].Level2.Name,
                        quantity: getListOrder[i].Quantity,
                        cost: getListOrder[i].Total
}
}
```

Передаю следующим образом:

```
"items": [listOrder]
```

И передается только 1, не могу понять в чем прикол)
Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: это потому что вы каждый цикл перезаписываете переменную

Comment: хм, может я туплю к ночи) а можно подробнее?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
listOrder = []
for (var i = 0; i < getListOrder.length; i++) {
  listOrder[i] = {
      externalItemId: getListOrder[i].ProductId,
      name: getListOrder[i].Name,
      category: getListOrder[i].Categories[0].Level2.Name,
      quantity: getListOrder[i].Quantity,
      cost: getListOrder[i].Total
  }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Видимо я туплю к ночи))

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать так

```js
let listOrder = getListOrder.map(item=>({
      externalItemId: item.ProductId,
      name: item.Name,
      category: item.Categories[0].Level2.Name,
      quantity: item.Quantity,
      cost: item.Total
  }));
```

Comment: Спасибо, ваш ответ тоже правильный)